# Heating outside air - how much humidity can it take?

Tags: thermodynamics, air, humidity

I am trying to figure out this problem - maybe it is simple for someone of you but I can't figure it out.

I have known variables of outside air temperature and relative humidity (RH), I am taking that air into the heater and have two fans that pump 640,000 m$^3$ per hour. The air is being heated up to 80 degrees Celsius.

My question is how can I calculate the RH of the heated air and is there any corelations between how much air is being pumped and how much can that air take RH from grain that I am trying to dry?

In short two fans with capacity of 640,000 m$^3$ per hour, 100 tons of grain, how to calculate best way and how much air does it need to dry it?

Comment: Are these grains suspended in a stream of air or piled on a floor and blown from above?

Comment: Grains are piled on the floor ( to be precise on sieves and air is blown from below them and trough them, layer is thick around 1.1 meter) @AlexTrounev

Comment: Is it organic grains?

Comment: Yes they are, barley grains @AlexTrounev

Comment: For barley grains, there is a temperature limit during drying. If the grains are supposed to be used for seeds, then 40C, and if not, then 60C.

Comment: I have should explained it better in the beggining - yes for dryer that are the temperatures forgot to mention that i am drying malt not barley @AlexTrounev

Answer (score 0):

The relative humidity of outside air heated to 80 C will always be very low. Worst case (beginning at 100 % and 35 C) would be 17 % or so, eyeballing the vapor pressure graph below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, and what do you think about other part - how much can  640,000 m3 per hour take humidity and is it beter to be blown faster or slower. Does slower air stream take more humidity? @pieter

Comment: @IvanĆalušić At 80 C, saturated air would contain 290 grams of water per cubic meter. But evaporation would cool the air, so one needs a psychrometric chart with adiabatic cooling lines, I will see if I can find one later tonight that goes up to 80 C.